# Different behaviour between the del list[-1] keyword and list = list[:-1]

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

So, I was trying this backtracking problem where I had to find all the possible outcomes of rolling `n` dices

My **backtracking code** looks like this

```
def dicRoll(n, chosen = []):
    if n==0:
        print(chosen)

    else:
        for i in range(1,7):
            chosen.append(i)
            dicRoll(n-1, chosen)
            del chosen[-1]
```

This seems to work perfectly fine! But as soon as I replace `del chosen[-1]` with `chosen = chosen[:-1]` things go wrong!

**Dysfunctional solution**:

```
def dicRoll(n, chosen = []):
    if n==0:
        print(chosen)

    else:
        for i in range(1,7):
            chosen.append(i)
            dicRoll(n-1, chosen)
            chosen = chosen[:-1]
```

I thought both do the exact same thing. What is the difference between the usage of the two lines causing different behaviors? Can someone please explain. I searched on SO, but there was no answer to a question which answered specifically this.

Comment: That is logical, since with `del` you change the *state* of the list, whereas with `chose = chosen[:-1]`, you create a *new* list. This thus means that references to the old list, still refer to a non-modified list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Your code uses a mutable default value for a parameter (namely, an empty list for the `chosen` parameter). [This usually is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). It would be better to use `None` as the default parameter, and replace it with an empty list. This matters if your function is called multiple times using the default parameter.